# How to delete rows from a table using an SQLAlchemy query without ORM?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm writing a quick and dirty maintenace script to delete some rows and would like to avoid having to bring my ORM classes/mappings over from the main project.  I have a query that looks similar to:

```
address_table = Table('address',metadata,autoload=True)
addresses = session.query(addresses_table).filter(addresses_table.c.retired == 1)
```

According to everything I've read, if I was using the ORM (not 'just' tables) and passed in something like:

```
addresses = session.query(Addresses).filter(addresses_table.c.retired == 1)
```

I could add a `.delete()` to the query, but when I try to do this using only tables I get a complaint:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2146, in delete
    target_cls = self._mapper_zero().class_
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'class_'
```

Which makes sense as its a table, not a class.  I'm quite green when it comes to SQLAlchemy, how should I be going about this?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Looking through some code where I did something similar, I believe this will do what you want.

```
d = addresses_table.delete().where(addresses_table.c.retired == 1)
d.execute()
```

Calling `delete()` on a table object gives you a `sql.expression` (if memory serves), that you then execute.  I've assumed above that the table is bound to a connection, which means you can just call `execute()` on it.  If not, you can pass the `d` to `execute(d)` on a connection.

See docs [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.TableClause.delete).

Comment: Thanks.  I see where I went wrong.  A combination of an old tutorial and out of date documentation.

Answer (score 56):

When you call `delete()` from a query object, SQLAlchemy performs a *bulk deletion*. And you need to choose a **strategy for the removal of matched objects from the session**. See the documentation [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.delete).

If you do not choose a strategy for the removal of matched objects from the session, then SQLAlchemy will try to evaluate the query’s criteria in Python straight on the objects in the session. **If evaluation of the criteria isn’t implemented, an error is raised.**

This is what is happening with your deletion.

If you only want to delete the records and do not care about the records in the session after the deletion, you can choose the strategy that ignores the session synchronization:

```
address_table = Table('address', metadata, autoload=True)
addresses = session.query(address_table).filter(address_table.c.retired == 1)
addresses.delete(synchronize_session=False)
```

Comment: False - don’t synchronize the session. This option is the most efficient and is reliable once the session is expired, which typically occurs after a commit(), or explicitly using expire_all(). Before the expiration, objects may still remain in the session which were in fact deleted which can lead to confusing results if they are accessed via get() or already loaded collections. https://kite.com/docs/python;sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.delete

Comment: Hi, Just want to know how we will get to know if objects are fetched using the filter query or not? What if it's empty and after executing the addresses.delete statement. It deleted 0 items. Is there any way to determine the length or number of rows fetched using addresses object just before executing delete statement?

Comment: Do not forget `db.session.commit()`

Answer (score -1):

```
create_engine(
            'mssql+pyodbc://@' + server + '/' + database + f'?trusted_connection=yes&driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server&fast_executemany={fast_executemany}')



with engine.connect() as connection:
            result = connection.execute(text("DELETE FROM [metadata].[test_table] WHERE [id] = 1309"))
            connection.commit()
            print(
                f"Deleted {result.rowcount} row(s) from ")
```