# Can't delete an object instance with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am querying the database for a certain object, and once I have found it, I want to delete from the database. I am doing it prtty much just like in the SQLAlchemy documentation, but it is not deleting as expected.

```
    interview = dbs.query(Interviews).\
        get(id_interview)

    try:
        dbs.delete(interview)
        dbs.flush()
    except Exception, e:
        import traceback
        logger.warn(traceback.format_exc())

    logger.info("***** Interview is: %s" % interview.name)
```

And the logger.info() prints the name of the interview object, which I suspect should be None.

What am I missing?

Comment: `dbs.query(...).delete()` should suffice. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882358/how-to-delete-rows-from-a-table-using-an-sqlalchemy-query-without-orm

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback?

Comment: You are assuming that deleting the database row also deletes the python object. Have you tried to query again to check if the row was actually deleted?

Comment: Your deleting the `interview` object will not set the interview object to None; it will just cause the row in the interview table to be deleted. As @goncalopp points out, check the database to make sure that the record really is deleted. Also, re: @fedorqui's comment, `query.delete()` is different than calling `dbs.delete(obj)`. For example, mapper events are not fired, nor are the Python relational cascades triggered. See [the docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.delete) for the query delete method for more info.

Comment: Goncalopp, Mark Hildreth, you were absolutely right. I wasn't considering the difference between deleting the object instance and deleting the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
interview = dbs.query(Interviews).get(id_interview)

if interview:
    try:
        dbs.delete(interview)
        dbs.flush()
    except Exception, e:
        import traceback
        logger.warn(traceback.format_exc())
        logger.info("***** Interview is: %s" % interview.name)
    else:
        logger.info("***** Interview not Found")
```