# Deleted rows from reflected table with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a table that I'm trying to delete data from. I have been using a Session() object to query data, and it works just fine. But when I go to delete a list of data, it fails.

```
# load engine and reflect.
engine = create_engine("...")
metadata = MetaData()
Session = sessionmaker(autoflush=True, autocommit=True)
Session.configure(bind=engine)
session = Session()
metadata.reflect(bind=engine)

# queries work.
table = Table("some_table", metadata, autoload_with=engine)
session.query(table).filter(table.c.column.between(dobj1,dobj2)).all()

# deletes do not.
session.query(table).filter(table.c.column.in_([1,2,3,4,5])).delete()
```

When I try to delete a bunch of rows, I get this:

```
File "/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1180, in _do_pre_synchronize
    target_cls = query._mapper_zero().class_
AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'class_'
```

I tried [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882358/how-to-delete-rows-from-a-table-using-an-sqlalchemy-query-without-orm) method, but it gives me this error:

```
File "/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/base.py", line 385, in execute
    raise exc.UnboundExecutionError(msg)
sqlalchemy.exc.UnboundExecutionError: This None is not directly bound to a Connection or Engine.Use the .execute() method of a Connection or Engine to execute this construct.
```

I tried to map it to a declarative base with `automap_base()`, but I just got different errors.

How can I delete rows from the table I loaded in the session I already have established?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query interface is part of the SQLAlchemy ORM, and `table` isn't mapped to a class.

The answer you linked to uses bound metadata (discouraged in modern SQLAlchemy). The following should work:

```
stmt = table.delete().where(table.c.column.in_([1,2,3,4,5]))

with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.execute(stmt)
```

**Edit:**

I realised that you can do this:

```
session.query(table).filter(table.c.column.in_([1,2,3,4,5])) \
    .delete(synchronize_session=False)
```

Comment: So it works as part of the queries because it doesn't need to be a mapped class, it just needs to describe the table object. However, because it's not mapped, statements cannot be arbitrarily executed on it?

Comment: So the edit worked, what's specific about synchonrising the session?

Comment: @mynameismevin The session uses the unit of work pattern to keep track of ORM objects, which you aren't using.

Comment: Gotcha! I'm only using the session as a way of connection sharing. Since I don't particularly care about the data model, is this still a sane way to utilise the non-ORM methods for SQLAlchemy?

Comment: Using the engine as in the first code block already uses the connection pool.