# SQLAlchemy delete based on dynamic where clause

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to use the sqlalchemy 'Delete' expression following this article:
[How to delete rows from a table using an SQLAlchemy query without ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882358/how-to-delete-rows-from-a-table-using-an-sqlalchemy-query-without-orm)

My problem is that the actual where clause (the column names on which to filter) needs to be passed dynamically.
But in the example, I see that the column names are not dynamic, only the filter values.
Am I missing something?

Basically, the below query filters on the column 'retired'. I want to pass 'retired' dynamically.:

```
  table_name = Table('address',metadata,autoload=True)
  d = table_name.delete().where(table_name.c.retired == 1)
  d.execute()
```

Comment: It's not clear how ***dynamic*** your columns are. Please provide more details about what the query looks like.

Comment: Do you mean using something like `table_name.columns["retired"]` instead of `table_name.c.retired` ?